Property of variation of curve on 2-sphere keeping the areas divided by the curve are unchanging
Assume $(S^2,g)$ is a Riemannian 2-sphere.  $\gamma:[0,a]\rightarrow S^2$ is a arc-parameterized  closed curve which divide $S^2$ into two parts.
$$
f(r,s): (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times [0,a] \rightarrow S^2
$$
is a variation of $\gamma$. For fixed $r$, the curve $f(r,\cdot)$ divide $S^2$ into two parts with areas $A_1(r), A_2(r)$.  Denote the length of the curve $f(r,\cdot)$ as $L(r)$.
If the $A_1(r), A_2(r)$ are unchanging respect to $r$, how to calculate
$$
\frac{d}{dr} L(r)  ~~?  \tag{1}
$$
Problem origin:  When I read the Hamilton's An isoperimetric estimate for the Ricci flow on the two-sphere, which is collected in Collected papers on Ricci flow.  He consider the one-parameter family of parallel curves of $\gamma$. Namely
$$
h(r,s) : (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times [0,a] \rightarrow S^2
$$
is variation of $\gamma$, but for fixed $r\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, the curve $h(r,\cdot)$ is at distance $r$ from $\gamma$. Then, he get
$$
\frac{d}{dr} L(r) = \int_{h(r,\cdot)} k_g ~ds   
\tag{2}
$$
where $k_g$ is geodesic curvature, $ds$ is arc length integral. Here  is the calculation.
Since  the variation keeping the area of each part unchang is mentioned in this problem,  I want to know the result of  (1)  which may like (2).

I wouldn't expect any similar result - the constraint on the distance of $h$ from $\gamma$ is a pointwise one, which is much stronger than your global constraint on areas. You can write down the first variation formula for an arbitrary variation (something like $\int h_r(r,s) \cdot \hat n k_g ds$) to complete $(1)$, but it wouldn't be using your assumption in any way.

@AnthonyCarapetis  Thanks, in my calculation, it is $\int \langle \nabla_T h_r(r,s), T\rangle ds$, where $T$ is the unit tangent vector of curve $h(r, \cdot)$.  I fail to get your $\int h_r(r,s) \cdot \hat n k_g ds$.     Is  $\hat n$  normal vector of curve $h(r, \cdot)$ ?

Yes, $\hat n$ is the unit normal (so that $\hat n k_g$ is the curvature vector). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation_of_area_formula

@AnthonyCarapetis  Thanks, I know too little.
